# Modify PlotTheme or/and ColorTheme (lighter colors)

Tags: graphics, color, plot-themes

```
TD = 8 + 12 + 12 + 12 + 33 + (61 + 1/4) + (41 + 1/4)/2 + 
   15/2 + (18 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4)/2 + 14/2;
CM = 15/2 + (61 + 1/4) + (41 + 1/4)/2 + 
   24 + (3 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4)/2 + 14/2 + (24 + 3/4) + 
   9/2;
TP = 2*90;

countsDim1 = {CM, TD, TP}/(TD + TP + CM);

n = 384 + 179;
labels = Placed[
   Row /@ Thread[{"" <> ToString@# <> 
         " H" & /@ {N[(n countsDim1[[1]]), 5], 
        N[(n countsDim1[[2]]), 5], Round@N[(n countsDim1)[[3]]]}}], 
   "RadialOuter"];
legend = Placed[
   SwatchLegend[Automatic, 
    Row /@ Thread[{{"CM ", "TD ", "TP "}, 
       Row[{"(", #, , ")"}] & /@ 
        Quantity[Round[100 countsDim1], "Percent"]}], 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman",
       FontColor -> Black, FontWeight -> Bold}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 26], {After, Bottom}, Framed];

type = Framed[
  PieChart[countsDim1, ChartLabels -> labels, ChartLegends -> legend, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
     FontColor -> Black, FontWeight -> Bold}, 
   PlotTheme -> {"Business", "PastelColor"}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Background -> LightYellow]
```

produces

[image]

I have tried the various combinations described in the dedicated page: [`PlotTheme`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotTheme.html).

Is it possible to have a `PlotTheme` or/and a `ColorTheme` with lighter colors?

Comment: try adding the option `ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.5]`?

Comment: @kglr : Thanks. I am wondering why cannot one use `ColorSchemes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using color blending function (Specifically : `Blend`) to make colors more lighter than they are.
For example , to make a red color lighter , you might write the following code :

`Blend[{Red, White}, 2.8/3]`

To see how this function can make lighter color blends , you might plot this graphic :

```
Graphics[Table[{Blend[{Red, White}, x], Disk[{8 x, 0}]}, {x, 0, 1, 
   0.1}]]
```

[image]

By doing this you can lighter the color of your plot:

```
TD = 8 + 12 + 12 + 12 + 33 + (61 + 1/4) + (41 + 1/4)/2 + 
   15/2 + (18 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4)/2 + 14/2;
CM = 15/2 + (61 + 1/4) + (41 + 1/4)/2 + 
   24 + (3 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4)/2 + 14/2 + (24 + 3/4) + 
   9/2;
TP = 2*90;

countsDim1 = {CM, TD, TP}/(TD + TP + CM);
cc = Blend[{Yellow, White}, 2.8/3];
n = 384 + 179;
labels = Placed[
   Row /@ Thread[{"" <> ToString@# <> 
         " H" & /@ {N[(n countsDim1[[1]]), 5], 
        N[(n countsDim1[[2]]), 5], Round@N[(n countsDim1)[[3]]]}}], 
   "RadialOuter"];
legend = Placed[
   SwatchLegend[Automatic, 
    Row /@ Thread[{{"CM ", "TD ", "TP "}, 
       Row[{"(", #, , ")"}] & /@ 
        Quantity[Round[100 countsDim1], "Percent"]}], 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman",
       FontColor -> Black, FontWeight -> Bold}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 26], {After, Bottom}, Framed];
type = Framed[
  PieChart[countsDim1, ChartLabels -> labels, ChartLegends -> legend, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 26, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
     FontColor -> Black, FontWeight -> Bold}, 
   PlotTheme -> {"Business", {"BackgroundColor", cc}}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium], Background -> cc]
```

This will give you a plot like this :

[image]